# error while input in structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Error after providing the input value of ID. But working when values directly assigned. Compiled Successfully.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>     

typedef struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int mob;
} stu;

void printstudent(stu *stud);

void main()
{
stu s1;

strcpy(s1.name,"name");

printf("Enter Student id");
scanf("%d",s1.id);

//s1.id=1;

printf("Enter Student Mob no");
scanf("%d",s1.mob);

//s1.mob=9911;

printstudent(&s1);

}

void printstudent(stu *stud)
{
printf("\n%d",stud->id);

printf("\n%s",stud->name);

printf("\n%d",stud->mob);
}
```

Error after providing the input value of ID. But working when values directly assigned.

Comment: Your `scanf` params seem to be missing some of these: `&`.

Comment: `scanf("%d",s1.id);` is wrong. Google how to use `scanf` to get `int`.

Comment: Compiler warnings help you to spot this kind of error.

Comment: Lol Mistake !!! Btw it said Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s1.id` and `s1.mob` are not pointers to the int, you should use `&s1.id` and `&s1.mob`

Comment: Thanks ! **embarrassed :/**